# Golang: Reading a text file with multi-line rows

Tags: go

I have a text file with multi-line rows, delimited by a blank line. What would be the best way to read that row for row in Go?

I think I may have to use a Scanner with my own Split function, but just wondering if there is a better/easier way that I am missing.

I have tried using my own Splitfunc based on bufio.ScanLines:

```
func MyScanLines(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte,    err error) {
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
            return 0, nil, nil
    }
    if i := bytes.IndexAny(data, "\n\n"); i >= 0 {
            return i + 1, dropCR(data[0:i]), nil
    }
    if atEOF {
            return len(data), dropCR(data), nil
    }
    return 0, nil, nil
}
```

But I get an error on the IndexAny call:
"syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline, expecting )" - Fixed that

Update: Fixed the syntax error above as suggested, but I only get the first line returned. I am reading the file as follows:

```
scanner.Split(MyScanLines)
scanner.Scan()
fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
```

Any suggestions?

Example of test file I am trying to read:

```
Name = "John"
Surname = "Smith"
Val1 = 700
Val2 = 800

Name = "Pete"
Surname = "Jones"
Val1 = 555
Val2 = 666
Val3 = 444

 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: Please provide sample of the file that you are trying to read.

Comment: @PrashantThakkar Example provided in original post now. Some Value Pairs may be in one record and not in the others and order is also not fixed.

Comment: Thanks, For the error that you are getting it clearly says that ")" is missing. Corrected: if i := bytes.IndexAny(data, "\n\n"); i >= 0 {

Comment: @PrashantThakkar Ah no!! I have been staring at that code and did not pick it up. Ugh. Thanks for that. Is the way I am doing it the recommended way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broken out. First understand scanning and make sure that is working:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(data))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        l := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(l)

    }

}

var data = `
Name = "John"
Surname = "Smith"
Val1 = 700
Val2 = 800

Name = "Pete"
Surname = "Jones"
Val1 = 555
Val2 = 666
Val3 = 444
`
```

Here is [the code on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FFP8bfO3AQ).

Next, gather the data you need into a slice. There is probably a way to check end of file, EOF, but I wasn't able to find it. This is what I came up with and this works:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    buffer := [][]string{}
    block := []string{}
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(data))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        l := scanner.Text()

        if len(l) != 0 {
            block = append(block, l)
            continue
        }

        if len(l) == 0 && len(block) != 0 {
            buffer = append(buffer, block)
            block = []string{}
            continue
        }

        if len(l) == 0 {
            block = []string{}
            continue
        }

    }

    if len(block) != 0 {
        buffer = append(buffer, block)
        block = []string{}
    }

    fmt.Println("PRINTING BUFFER - END OF PROGRAM - ALL DATA PROCESSED:", buffer)

}

var data = `
Name = "John"
Surname = "Smith"
Val1 = 700
Val2 = 800

Name = "Pete"
Surname = "Jones"
Val1 = 555
Val2 = 666
Val3 = 444
`
```

Here is [the code on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Cq26494Z-_).

Comment: Thanks very much for this!

Comment: You basically took my answer and reposted it… you didn't even change the variables names to simulate solving the problem yourself. Pitiful…

Comment: The intent is the solution, not IP rights or genius originality. Your code wasn't working. I provided another iteration. I pointed out where I felt my code could be improved. Somebody improved it, providing another iteration. Team work focused on the solution. To me, that's what stackoverflow is about: coders coming together to help each other. I'm not trying to steal your code. Chill and play nice. Name calling is uncalled for.

Answer (score 2):

You way is working, but I would advise you to use a `bufio.Scanner`, which defaults to scanning line by line.
Then, you just start reading your file line by line and populating your struct. When encountering a blank line, put your struct into a slice and start with a new one.

Here is an example taken from one of my open source projects that demonstrate it:

```
buffer := [][]string{}
block := []string{}
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(data))
for scanner.Scan() {
    l := scanner.Text()

    if len(strings.TrimSpace(l)) != 0 {
        block = append(block, l)
        continue
    }

    // At this point, the script has reached an empty line,
    // which means the block is ready to be processed.
    // If the block is not empty, append it to the buffer and empty it.
    if len(block) != 0 {
        buffer = append(buffer, block)
        block = []string{}
    }
}

if len(block) != 0 {
    buffer = append(buffer, block)
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. Check it out here on the Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/v5aOCK7zRG

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it, I effectively inverted a condition while removing irrelevant context from my code. I fixed it, and added a check in the end to account for the end of file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate approach to do the same, using `bufio.Reader`. The logic is almost similar to [Elwiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3472656/elwinar)'s answer.

`myReadLine` function below uses `bufio.Reader` to read the next multiline entry in the file.

```
func myReadLine(file *os.File, reader *bufio.Reader) (lines []string, err error){
  for {
    line, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
    if err != nil || len(line) == 0 {
      break
    }
    lines = append(lines, string(line))
  }
  return lines, err
}
```

The below code sample illustrates sample usage of the above function:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
for {
    lines, err := myReadLine(file, reader)
    if err != nil || len(lines) == 0 { 
        break 
    }
    fmt.Println(lines)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bufio.Scan() returns false on EOF.
We will return a second 'ok' argument, so our caller can tell if we have
hit the end of our input.

Best to accumulate our record in a slice of strings, and concatenate at the end.
The obvious way of appending each line in turn to the result string will work, but is O(n^2) in the number of lines.

Putting it all together:

```
func ReadBlock(scanner *bufio.Scanner) (string, bool) {
    var o []string
    if scanner.Scan() == false {
        return "", false
    }

    for len(scanner.Text()) > 0 {
        o = append(o, scanner.Text())
        if scanner.Scan() == false {
            break
        }
    }
    return strings.Join(o, " "), true
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/C_fB8iaYJo

p.s. looking at your input, I suspect you would want to return the result as a map rather than a concatenated string.